# Interaction .asp with .swf flash - good on IIS6, bad on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, flash, swf

I can't make my app work after migration from IIS6 to IIS7. Problem is described below.

*My app*: in my app I use 'flash.swf'. This .swf appeals to .asp, which contains only:

```
Response.write "<myNode>test_is_ok</myNode>"
```

.swf must get it and show "test_is_ok". And it is really ok on IIS6 2003, but on IIS7 2008R2 .swf shows me "undefined".

*Situation*: Separate request from IE to .asp gets "test_is_ok" on both computers. If .swf from one computer appeals to .asp on another - nothing works. If I delete .asp, then .swf also shows "undefined", so I think it don't really appeals to .asp on IIS7.

Suggest me, please, something, what can help.

Answer (score 0):

Four days to solve this problem is too much. I decided not to go up the hill, but around it. Quickly turned to remake part of a project that responsible for connection with flash on ASP.NET, at the same time I reduced the code.

By the way, I could not run this simple application on IIS7, but on IIS6 - with no problems. On IIS7 I get endless "Loading data...." after clicking submit-button.

*[article: http://www.asp101.com/articles/flash/ ]  [code may be downloaded from article]*

Unfortunately, I still did not find solution.